# Virtual function with non-shared method

Tags: c++, inheritance, crtp

I'm on a personal project and I need to do something unusual. My code is kinda long but the problem comes from the structure so I'll use a very simplified version of the problem.

- I have two classes (A and B), with B derived from A.
- B uses every attributes and methods of A, including one which creates a modified
  clone of the instance of the class.

The problem is that I need to be able to use a method of B **after cloning** (moo in this case) that doesn't exists in A. I tried to make my methods virtual but it doesn't fix the problem. Is there any way to do this without CRTP ?

I really don't want to use CRTP because it would be really complicated.
(In my real code I have a chain of 4 class inheritances, and all 4 are already templated)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    public:

        /*Common function*/
        virtual void foo(){
            std::cout << "call from A" << std::endl;
        }

        A* clone(){
            /*
            ...
            ...   Code I don't want to write again for B
            ...
            */
            return this;
        }

};

class B: public A
{

        
    public:

        /*Common function*/
        virtual void foo(){
            std::cout << "call from B" << std::endl;
        }

        /*Not derived from A*/
        void moo(){ //Doesn't work even with virtual keyword
            std::cout << "only exist in B" << std::endl;
        }
};


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    auto tB = new B();

    tB->foo();
    tB->moo();
    tB->clone()->foo();
    tB->clone()->moo();


    return 0;
}
```

Compilator:

```
error: 'class A' has no member named 'moo'; did you mean 'foo'?
   38 |     tB->clone()->moo();
      |                  ^~~
      |                  foo
```

I'm not English so sorry if it's unclear.

Comment: There is no way to avoid CRTP or something similar using template because you basically want `clone()` to return a different type depending on the you call it from. It's kind of weird that your `clone()` is non-virtual and have a shared implementation... Usually `clone()` is the method you use to create a new instance of the right class because the parent class has no way of knowing how to create child classes, your design looks kind of flawed to me, maybe that's an XY problem.

Comment: The "Code [you] don't want to write again for B" in the `clone` function, I assume it will be common between `A` and `B`? Then if it's initialization code of the objects, do it in the `A` constructor instead? Or if it's not possible, how about a "setup"-type function which is called by both `A::clone` and `B::clone` after object creation?

Comment: @DrewDormann I thought `tB` was a `A*` to a `B` but it is a `B*`. You can use `virtual` with a covariant type. Edit : But this will require the use of raw pointers, and the usage would be incompatible with that as it will necessarily leak the new instance.

Comment: As for the return-type, there's really no good way around the CRTP. Perhaps you could use multiple inheritance, so both `A` and `B` inherit from a `template<typename T> Clonable` template which does the cloning?

Comment: You could add a template argument to `clone` to specify the dynamic type you know the instance has and use `dynamic_cast` to check if that guess is accurate. You'll also want to return a `std::unique_ptr<T>` instead of a `T*` In addition to being a good rule of thumb, it will be next to impossible to effectively manually `delete` the cloned instance in the use case shown in the question.

Comment: The `clone()` member function *slices*.  It doesn't actually **clone**, since it slices to the base class.

Comment: @Eljay There is no slicing here since it returns a pointer, but there is also no cloning if it returns `this`.

Comment: @Holt • Good point, I did not notice that `clone()` is `return this;` at the end.  I'm not sure why that function is called `clone()` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to the comments, my research and how I think c++ works, I give up finding something that looks like virtual methods and still be satisfying.

So I resolved to use the CRTP, for those who are interested here's the code of my model of a 3 (I deleted one) inherited class CRTP with an additional type template argument :)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

//CRTPI = "CRTP Interface", used for inheritances between CRTPs

template<typename Derived, typename T>
class CRTPI_A
{
    protected:
        T x = 0;


    public:

        T getX(){
            return x;
        }

        Derived* clone(){
            /*
            ...
            ...   Code I don't want to write again for B and it's childs
            ...
            */
            return new Derived();
        }

};

template<typename Derived, typename T>
class CRTPI_B: public CRTPI_A<Derived, T>
{
    public:

        //Only for B and its childs
        void iwd(){
            std::cout << "Hi, i'm a B child !" << std::endl;
        }


};

template<typename Derived, typename T>
class CRTPI_C: public CRTPI_B<Derived, T>{};

template<typename T>
class A: public CRTPI_A<A<T>, T>
{
    public:

        A(){};

        A(T z){
            this->x = z;
        }

        void foo(){
            std::cout << "call from A" << std::endl;
        }
};

template<typename T>
class B: public CRTPI_B<B<T>, T>
{

        
    public:

        B(){};

        B(T z){
            this->x = z;
        }

        void foo(){
            std::cout << "call from B" << std::endl;
        }

        //Not in CRTP interface so won't be inherited by C
        void UwU(){
            std::cout << "I'm exclusive to B" << std::endl;
        }

};

template<typename T>
class C: public CRTPI_C<C<T>, T>
{
    public:

        C(){};

        C(T z){
            this->x = z;
        };

        void foo(){
            std::cout << "call from C" << std::endl;
        }
};


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    auto tA = new A<char>('A');
    auto tB = new B<int>(2);
    auto tC = new C<float>(420.69);


    tA->foo();
    tA->clone()->foo();

    printf("\n");

    tB->foo();
    tB->iwd();
    tB->clone()->foo();
    tB->clone()->iwd();

    tB->UwU();

    printf("\n");

    tC->foo();
    tC->iwd();
    // tC->UwU(); //Won't work but that's planned

    std::cout << "\n" << tA->getX() << ":" << tB->getX() <<":" << tC->getX() << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Note that, here, the CRTP interface for C is optional because it has no child class and no exclusive methods, so we can just write:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class C: CRTPI_B<C<T>, T>
{
    ...
}
```